# Window with no title bar in wxWindows/wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, titlebar, wxwidgets

Is there a way to have a window without a title bar using [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `style=wx.NO_BORDER` can remove all of the borders including title bar. Or `style=wx.CAPTION` can remove all buttons from title bar. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @ton1c: perhaps, i'll try it out monday

Comment: @ton1c: yep, that's what i was looking for, feel free to answer & i will upvote you & accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wx.NO_BORDER` - Displays no border, overriding the default border style for the window. [Source](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html)

`wx.CAPTION` - Removes all buttons from the title bar. [Source 1](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ParentModalDialog) [Source 2](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/firststeps/)